# I2S Data Structure (Inter-IC Sound)

Tags: embedded, i2s

There are tons of electrical descriptions of I2S; however, I cannot find information about how the data is formatted/structured. What I mean by format is, what does a value on the serial data line mean? Do these values have information on volume, pitch, or something else?

As an application example, I have a .wav audio file. I unpacked the file and obtained a stream of data samples. How should this sample data be transmitted on I2S so that a receiver can play the audio? 0x 0011 2233 4455 6677 8899 AABB CCDD EEFF 0011 2233 4455 ... and so on. Should these values be formatted in some way that is meaningful to the receiver? Maybe something like 0x0011____, 0x2233____, where blank means other miscellaneous information?

Let's assume for the case of I2S Standard, 24 bits per sample. Any information would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the I²S specification?

Comment: Same question in StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62187477/i2s-data-structure-inter-ic-sound)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I2S data for each sample is is the amplitude of that sample. It is sent MSB first. Typically data frames have 16, 24, or 32 bits per sample, and both devices must be configured to matching format. If you have 24-bit data from WAV file but 32-bit frames then data must be expanded correctly with zeroes. The WAV file most likely stores least significant byte first so perhaps some shifting or swapping is needed to send it. It should be pretty straightforward but depends on which MCU or DAC you are working on.